# Optimisation with matlab - particleswarm / genetic algorithm

Tags: matlab, optimization, genetic-algorithm, particle-swarm

I am trying to use particle-swarm/genetic algorithm to solve a maxima problem. However, the function keeps giving me the minima. How to change it such that it finds for the maxima.

My simple code is as follows:

```
options = optimoptions('particleswarm','Swarmsize',100);

[x2,fval2] = particleswarm(Rmodel.predictFcn,nvar,lb,ub,options);
```

`Rmodel` is a linear regression model. I am only using it for testing.

Answer (score 1):

From https://se.mathworks.com/help/gads/particleswarm.html:

> `x = particleswarm(fun,nvars)` attempts to find a vector `x` that achieves
>   a local minimum of `fun`. `nvars` is the dimension (number of design
>   variables) of `fun`.

I don't have access to global optimization toolbox to test the particleswarm function but if I understand correctly, all you need is to flip the function and instead of looking for the minima of Rmodel.predictFcn, you look for the minima of -Rmodel.predictFcn (notice the minus sign).

Comment: I have tried this before but it gives me Undefined unary operator '-' for
input arguments of type 'function_handle'.

Answer (score 0):

it ok i found it. In matlab, you cannot simply use -Rmodel.predictFcn.

you need to define a function handler.
e.g invPredict = @(x) -Rmodel.predictFcn(x)